# jQuery UI autocomplete and multiple values in IE6,7,8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete that works in most browsers but only kind of works in IE6,7,8 (works in IE9)
after selecting the first value, if I press the down arrow to get the list of possible values. I get a list of exactly one item, namely the one already selected. I'd like the entire list.

```
function split(term){
     return term.split(/,\s*/);
}

control.autocomplete({
        minLength: minLength,
        source: function (request, response) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                values, split(request.term).pop()));
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            updateConfiguration();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that IE6,7 and 8 handles the regex in the split function different than IE9, Chrome and FF. if the last element consists of only whitespace then it will be omitted.

Changing the splite funciton to the below fixed this

```
function split(val) {
    //IE deviates from all other browser if the last entry is empty
    var temp = val.trim();
    var endsWithComma = temp.substring(temp.length-1) === ",";
    temp = endsWithComma ? temp.substring(0,temp.length-1) : temp;
    var values = temp.split(/,\s*/);
    if(endsWithComma)
      values[values.length] = " ";
    return values;
}
```